Why max() doesn't work but idxmax() does on 'category' dtype in Pandas?
Why doesn't max() work but idxmax() does on 'category' dtype in Pandas?
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series([1, 4, 3], index=['a', 'b', 'c'])
s = s.astype('category')

# print(s.max())  # it doesn't work.
# "you can use .as_ordered() to change the Categorical to an ordered one"

print(s.idxmax())

If s.max() does not work, it seems logical that idxmax() shouldn't work too!
I have read the documentation but still do not understand why s.max() does not work while s.idxmax() does.

"Why doesn't max work" - categories aren't ordered, so there isn't a max item. "Why does idxmax work" - unsure, but what's the use case? Stack Overflow is for practical programming problems, so questions that don't have a practical implementation are usually off-topic. If you do have a use case, feel free to [edit] this question or ask a new one to make that more clear!

If you look at the documentation:

In contrast to statistical categorical variables, categorical data might have an order (e.g. ‘strongly agree’ vs ‘agree’ or ‘first observation’ vs. ‘second observation’), but numerical operations (additions, divisions, …) are not possible.

max() requires a way to compare the values to determine the maximum, and unordered categories do not have a defined order for comparison.
Further in the documentation, Sorting and order:

If categorical data is ordered (s.cat.ordered == True), then the order of the categories has a meaning and certain operations are possible. If the categorical is unordered, .min()/.max() will raise a TypeError.

So that is the reason for the error when using s.max on your series.
Why idxmax works?
For this, I encourage you to read the source. This is the key part:
if numeric_only:
    data = self._get_numeric_data()
else:
    data = self

res = data._reduce(
    nanops.nanargmax, "argmax", axis=axis, skipna=skipna, numeric_only=False
)

In short, idxmax relies on the internal codes of the categorical data, and so it finds the index of the maximum value without needing the categories to be ordered.
idxmax return index of first occurrence of maximum. And so in your series, it finds the maximum of values 4, and returns the index of that value which is b.
